# Prevent closing Chrome extension popup after closing Javascript alert

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Up until testing today, the default behaviour when closing a Javascript alert originated from a Chrome Extension popup was the alert closing but the Chrome popup staying open. Just now when testing, I found both the alert and the extension popup close when I clear the Javascript alert. What changed? Is there a way to revert to the previous behaviour?

Really inconvenient to have to re-click on the popup after interacting with the Javascript alert.

Comment: Don't use alerts. Display the message as a DOM element in the popup itself.

Comment: Fair suggestion. That said, is there a way to revert back to the previous behaviour if alerts need to be used for some reason?

Comment: You can report it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm! reported here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1201295

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a bug that was introduced and resolved here:
bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1201295

Should be fixed in following MacOS Chrome versions